# Angular 1 - complex ng-repeat objects/arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ui-select

I have an array with 3 object then 1 object (or more depending on the choice of 3 first objects) then 5 arrays (or more according to the choice of the 5 arrays)

```
repeat="item in $ctrl.project[$ctrl.checkProject()].productType[$ctrl.ckeckProductType()]

//method to search for the item
      checkProject() {
        if (this.project.label === 'business') {
          return 0
        } else if(this.project.label === 'realEstate') {
          return 1
        } else if (this.project.label === 'smallBusiness'){
          return 2
        }
      }
```

And the same for the `ckeckProductType()` method

Is there not a more sophisticated solution to energize all this?

Comment: Of course - Run both functions **only once** in the controller, instead of `return 0/1/2;`  save the value: `this.project_label = this.checkProject();` and  `this.project_type = this.ckeckProductType();` then in the loop, use those properties: `item in $ctrl.project[$ctrl.project_label].productType[$ctrl.project_type]`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to wrap your result sequence into the method. Smth like this:

```
data-ng-repeat = "object in getMyObjects() track by $index"
```

With this you will move you selecting logic to the controller where it should be. 
But, it is not nice from the performance side. Function will be called each digest and will eat your resources.

Another approach is to define sequence's dependencies (this.project.label and so on) and track their update. When they will be updated, you will change your sequence. This approach requires more code and it little bit harder to maintain but it little bit faster (until your sequence not contain 1000+ items)

So it is up to you what way to go. 
Hope this helps.

P.S. There is third approach. Merge all into one sequence and write filter for this. 
P.P.S. The last is possible but do not do this, it was a small evening joke.